# Find the next number in the series 7726, 635, 64, 9

Tags: pattern, number-sequence

Find the next number in the series.
7726, 635, 64, 9[image]

Comment: Please check the edits people.

Comment: Might want to include where you got the puzzle since (based on the screenshot) you did not create it yourself.

Comment: It came in the recent qualifying aptitude question paper of the company IBM for the post of a technical consultant.

Comment: This is interesting, because I have seen both your puzzle as well as the one below by searching online. Here is an example of [mine](https://m4maths.com/13593-7776-625-64-9.html) and [another](https://q4interview.com/aptitude-ques-ans-discussion.php?qid=3067&t=70&qnum=76&cat=29); here is an example of [yours](https://m4maths.com/34168-What-is-the-next-number-of-the-following-sequences-1-4-2--4--8-32-26--156-2-5-10.html). Indeed, there seems to be a variety of "puzzles", as [here's another variation](https://m4maths.com/17654-7776-625-44-9.html). All of them "come from IBM aptitude tests".

Comment: My bad... BTW thanks for the correct question.

Comment: No worries! It can be tough when there are multiple variations of a question around. I'd imagine that the actual aptitude test will have the correct question. Good luck, @AvantikaSanodia!! :)

Comment: You should charge your battery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there might be a few typos, because it looks like the pattern is

> $6^5$, $5^4$, $4^3$, $3^2$, which means the next number is $2^1 = 2$.

The pattern (if this is correct) is then

> 7776, 625, 64, 9, 2